# Unable to load the requested class

Tags: codeigniter, ubuntu, mpdf

Me encontraba desarrollando en W7 y al querer seguir el rabajo en Ubuntu, me aparece el mensaje:

> Unable to load the requested class: MPDF

El autoload.php:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'email', 'session', 'Mpdf');
```

La clase está definida:

```
class mPDF{}
```

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Hola Gaby bienvenida a SOes, que version de codeigniter usas?

Comment: Hola. Esta es la documentación: `@link https://codeigniter.com
  @since Version 1.0.0`

Comment: Disculpa, por ignorancia me había fijado mal. Es la versión 3.1.0 `define('CI_VERSION', '3.1.0');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Independientemente del sistema operativo codeigniter 3 maneja sus reglas a la hora de nombrar clases y archivos.

Un clase debe tener la primera letra mayuscula, por ejemplo:

```
class Blog extends CI_Controller {
    public function index(){
        echo 'Hello World!';
    }
}
```

Tu tienes tu clase asi:

```
class mPDF{}
```

Por lo que no la va a encontrar, deberías cambiarla a:

```
class Mpdf{}
```

Asi mismo el archivo que contiene tu clase debe llamarse de la misma manera, en tu caso seria:

```
Mpdf.php
```

Y al momento de cargarla, podrias usar minusculas.

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'email', 'session', 'mpdf');
```

Si tu libreria esta dentro de un directorio entonces la carga debe hacerse con el directorio

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'email', 'session', 'mpdf/mpdf');
```

Comment: Me da el mismo error: `Unable to load the requested class: Mpdf`.

Comment: En el directorio está así:           Aplication -> Libraries ->mpdf.   En **Mpdf.php** tengo:   
`class Mpdf
{var $useFixedNormalLineHeight;  
var $useFixedTextBaseline;  
.... }`.   Y el autoload lo tengo así:   `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'email', 'session', 'mpdf');`

Comment: Aplication -> Libraries ->mpdf es un directorio y dentro tienes Mpdf.php?

Comment: Exacto. mpdf es el directorio que me descargué de internet, como quien diria "la libreria mpdf"

Comment: Entonces la carga de la libreria deberia ser 'mpdf/mpdf' ya que la tienes dentro de un directorio. Acabo de editar la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias !!! Problema solucionado, aunque apareció uno nuevo. `Mpdf has a deprecated constructor`. ¿Hay que definir algo?¿Problemas de compatibilidad? Gracias por responder

Comment: Si la respuesta te sirvió no olvides marcarla como solución a tu pregunta. Respondiendo la otra inquietud, depende de la version de PHP que manejes.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 asi como todos sus sucesores no son case sensitive, mientras que los sistemas basados en UNIX sí. Y es el caso de Linux y tambien MacOS, por ende tienes que verificar como estan los nombres de los archivos.php para lograrlos leer en la carga de autoload

Comment: Gracias. Imaginé que era por el lado del case sensitive, pero he revisado y no encuentro el error. ¿Tiene que estar todo en minúscula?¿CamelCase? Gracias